# Selector to get all text from tag EXCEPT text in specific nested tag

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

**Objective:** Extract all the text in a tag EXCEPT from a header tag.

**Input html:** (generated by JSP - I have no control over the format or spaces) - can be 500 or more rows

```
<td class="aaaColumn">    <h4>Header text:</h4>      some data         <br />       some more data [XX].   </td>
```

**What have I tried:**

```
var o = "aaa";
var arr = $.trim(
$("."+o+"Column").text()
.replace(/[\[\]]/g," "))
.split(" ");
```

**Current output:**

IE gives me

```
Header
text:some
data
some
more
data
XX
```

and Fx gives me

```
Header
text:
some
data
some
more
data
XX
```

**What I need:**

IE and Fx (and all other browsers)

```
some
data
some
more
data
XX
```

So something like (I am guessing)

`$("."+o+"Column :not('h4')").text()`

Comment: hi, i did what you want just have look to demo that i did on the jsfiddle in my answer....reply me if there is any problem with this ...

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the output you want just have look to it.....

## DEMO

```
$("#aaaColumn").clone()    //clone the element
         .children() //select all the children
         .remove()   //remove all the children
         .end()  //again go back to selected element
         .text();    //get the text of element
```

Comment: Thanks - however it looks VERY expensive and fails if I add a `<span>Even more data</span>` but works again if I do `remove("h4")`